Django,Docker caching previsouly setup email in he settings.py
I have changed my backend email when I run in docker compose it uses the previous email  thus an error but when i run in manage.py runserver mode there is no error.
I want  when i run in docker mode for it  to read the new email that i have setup

I am assuming that you are talking about the Dockerfile. If that is the case, then you need to try composing with the --build tag to see the changes getting reflected.
docker compose up --build

